# Is a spinlock necessary in this Linux device driver code?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is the following Linux device driver code safe, or do I need to protect access to `interrupt_flag` with a spinlock?

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq_head);
static int interrupt_flag = 0;

static ssize_t my_write(struct file* filp, const char* __user buffer, size_t length, loff_t* offset)
{
   interrupt_flag = 0;   
   wait_event_interruptible(wq_head, interrupt_flag != 0);
}

static irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void* dev_id)
{
   interrupt_flag = 1;
   wake_up_interruptible(&wq_head);
   return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Basically, I kick off some event in `my_write()` and wait for the interrupt to indicate that it completes.

If so, which form of `spin_lock()` do I need to use?  I thought `spin_lock_irq()` was appropriate, but when I tried that I got a warning about the IRQ handler enabling interrupts.

Doesn't `wait_event_interruptible` evaluate the `interrupt_flag != 0` condition?  That would imply that the lock should be held while it reads the flag, right?

Comment: Try. `spin_lock_irqsave()`

Comment: It almost surely needs to be protected. Whether a spin lock or a different locking mechanism is most appropriate can't be determined without more information, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lock is needed in the example given. Memory barriers are needed after the store of the flag, and before the load -- to ensure visibility to the flag -- but the wait_event_* and wake_up_* functions provide those. See the section entitled "Sleep and wake-up functions" in this document: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Before adding a lock, consider what is being protected. Generally locks are needed if you're setting two or more separate pieces of data and you need to ensure that another cpu/core doesn't see an incomplete intermediate state (after you started but before you finished). In this case, there's no point in protecting the storing / loading of the flag value because stores and loads of a properly aligned integer are always atomic.

So, depending on what else your driver is doing, it's quite possible you do need a lock, but it isn't needed for the snippet you've provided.

Comment: Referring to the "stores and loads of a properly aligned integer are always atomic" part, and without the the `wait_*` and `wake_up_*` functions,  does this mean that _no_ locking is needed when sharing `int` between process context and kernel context ? What about SMP ?

Comment: That's right. No lock is needed if you're only sharing an int. This doesn't change with SMP. Assume var is 0. Assume core0 sets var to 1 at some point. Assume core1 is looking at var. At any point in time, core1 sees var as having either 0 in it (before the change) or 1 (after the change). Grabbing a lock around setting it (or examining it) doesn't change that. core1 still sees either 0 or 1. Nothing is accomplished by locking.

Comment: I agree that this correct for most archs. I went through `atomic_t` (which is just a wrapper to `int`) and the `atomic_set()`. On almost all archs, `atomic_set()` is a macro directly setting the internal `int` to the required value. Except on sparc, parisc and metag, where this operation is protected with locks and sometimes irq disable (see arch/sparc/lib/atomic32.c for example). I am not sure of the reason for this protection, but I guess this makes your answer correct for all archs except those three. Or did I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: This is done to play nice with the other "atomic" operations (like atomic_xchg) on architectures that don't implement it in hardware. For example, if you want to set a value to 1, but only if it is not currently zero (say) and you don't have an atomic XCHG instruction like Intel (or another equivalent mechanism like LL/SC), a spinlock is one way to accomplish that, but then you have to ensure that atomic_set takes the lock too. See the note at atomic_set in the metag arch for an example. This is a sequence of related operations that must not appear in an intermediate state.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need a lock. With the given example (that uses `int` and no specific arch is mentioned), the process context may be interrupted while accessing the `interrupt_flag`. Upon return from the IRQ, it may continue and `interrupt_flag` may be left in inconsistent state.

Try this:

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq_head);
static int interrupt_flag = 0;
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(lock);

static ssize_t my_write(struct file* filp, const char* __user buffer, size_t length, loff_t* offset)
{
   /* spin_lock_irq() or spin_lock_irqsave() is OK here */
   spin_lock_irq(&lock);
   interrupt_flag = 0;
   spin_unlock_irq(&lock);

   wait_event_interruptible(wq_head, interrupt_flag != 0);
}

static irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void* dev_id)
{
   unsigned long flags;

   spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
   interrupt_flag = 1;
   spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);

   wake_up_interruptible(&wq_head);
   return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

IMHO, the code has to be written without making any arch or compiler-related assumptions (like the 'properly aligned integer' in Gil Hamilton answer).

Now if we can change the code and use `atomic_t` instead of the `int` flag, then no locks should be needed.

Comment: why?  what race does the lock protect against?

Comment: There are no architectures that the Linux kernel runs on where declaring an int variable at file scope will result in an unaligned variable, and no architectures where access to an aligned int is not atomic.